# Automounted volume is empty El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, nas, synology

I'm trying to use OSX's automount utility (autofs) to prevent dismounts of a local Synology NAS using the steps in this tutorial [1](http://blog.grapii.com/2015/06/keep-network-drives-mounted-on-mac-os-x-using-autofs/). Although there are no errors, mount points and folders are created after executing automount -vc, the folders are empty in Finder and via Console. All the other tutorials and articles relating to this technique use exactly the same technique but I'm guessing I'm missing something silly here.

Mounting the drive manually works fine. Networking is not my 'thing' so pointers would be gratefully accepted.